# stackdump is not created if exe is not run from cygwin terminal

Tags: cygwin

I have an application which is compiled in cygwin. The exe crashes once in a while. If exe is run from cygwin terminal a stackdump file is created. If exe is copied to another folder along with `cygwin1.dll` and the exe crashes, then no stackdump file is created.

I want a stackdump file to be created even if the exe is run not from cygwin terminal.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

When you start a cygwin executable from windows, or a command prompt, the `CYGWIN` environment variable is usually not set. The shortcut or batch file which starts the cygwin terminal sometimes sets this variable. One of the options that can be set by this variable determines what program is called by windows when the application crashes. The `/bin/dumper.exe` program generates the stackdump you want.

To get around your problem, I always set the CYGWIN variable from the control panel, computer properties, advances system settings, environment variables, user variables. (Win7 - YMMV). E.g. `CYGWIN=error_start=d:\cygwin64\bin\dumper.exe`

See [The CYGWIN Environment variable](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-cygwinenv.html) for more information.